# How do i get data of each downloaded Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, server

so i have the following macro, which downloads several workbooks from a company webpage. Now i want to extract Data out of every workbook, so during each loop, before moving to the download of the next workbook.
How do i do that ?
EDIT: Actually it doesnt matter if i download all the files first and then get the data or get the data of each file in its own loop.

```
Sub Downloaden_Reviews()


Dim dlURL As String
Dim i As Range
Dim versch As String
Dim ordner As String

'Select Saving path
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Select where to save"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath

If .Show = -1 Then
ordner = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With
'Ende order

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each i In ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B100")
If i = "" Then
End
End If

versch = i.Offset(0, -1)
dlURL = "URL of the webpage"

Dim HttpReq As Object
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

HttpReq.Open "GET", dlURL, False
HttpReq.send

dlURL = HttpReq.responseBody
If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStrm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStrm.Open
    oStrm.Type = 1
    oStrm.Write HttpReq.responseBody
    oStrm.SaveToFile [ordner] & "\" & [i] & ".xlsm", 1 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite"
    oStrm.Close
End If
Next
```

Comment: Your "URL of the webpage" does not include the file name?

Comment: the url is variable and is adjusted with values, that i grab from the current workbook. i had to delete the link, since its a private company link

Comment: No problem, I did not want to see the real link. The question was different:  Doesn't the link include the file/workbook name? I do not ask that from curiosity...

Comment: it does include parts of the file name. The file name after downloading it, is composed of different parts, taken from the link

Comment: So, your link isn't is something like "http://Your_Path/workbooks/YourWorkbook.xlsm"? Even if "YourWorkbook" is composed of different parts to be rebuilt in code...

Comment: Here an example for the link:
"https://plm.corp.0//tvc-action/downloadFiles?objectId=4706&object=" & [i] & "_" & [versch] .xlsm"

Comment: I cannot see too much... But, do you have a site path separated by "/" and then the workbook name? I do not care about the way the name was built... If you write that path in a browser, is the file downloaded in your computer? After "...Object=" is your workbook name?

Comment: Seems like i dont quite get what your point is :( Yes, if i copy the path into the browser, the file is downloaded. .... & [i] & "_" & [versch] .xlsm..... this is the variable name/download path for each file. [i] & [versch] are the variables

Comment: OK. I will post a piece of code to try it, in order to download such a file. I cannot do that in comment, in a way to be something easy to be understood, so I will post it like an answer. Please confirm that it downloads your file in your Path.

Comment: I deleted my code able to download. So, you can download and save all your workbooks in a computer path. Correct? If yes, what do you mean by "get the data of each file"? What do you want to do with "data" in discussion? Do your files have only a single sheet?  If not, all of them have the same number of sheets? What do you want to do with their content? To process them in a specific way and then save? To copy all data in another workbook? Part of the data, according to some rules? How can we help if you do not describe at all what your request/need mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following code. Works for my case.

```
Sub Aus_allen()
    Dim strDatei As String, strPfad As String, strTyp As String
    Dim wbX As Workbook, wksX As Worksheet, wksN As Worksheet
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strPfad = "C:\Users\p\MakroTest\"                 'Pfad anpassen
    strTyp = "xlsm"                      'Dareityp anpassen
    Set wksN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")   'Zieltabelle
    strDatei = Dir(strPfad & "\*." & strTyp)
    Do Until strDatei = ""
        Set wbX = Workbooks.Open(strPfad & "\" & strDatei)
        Set wksX = wbX.Sheets(1)
        wksN.Cells(8, 5) = wksX.Cells(8, 5)
        wbX.Close False
        strDatei = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: And does this code what you need? If yes, good for you! Please consider your question asked by yourself. If not, who do you think must tell us what you want/need against what the code does...?